# Variables with set are not passed when using redirect method at CakePHP 2.2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.2

Is there any way to pass variables to the view i am going to redirect the user?
I noticed this doesn't work:

```
$this->set('var', 'value')
$this->redirect(array('controller' => 'example', 'action' => 'view', $this->request->data['Post']['id']));
```

The redirection has to be done. It's a "Comment" add action called from the "Post" view.
I just want the textarea to still having the previous entered text before the submit.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to think really hard. on what you expect it to do and why it would never work (at least not until the basic physical laws are proven wrong)...

Comment: Redirect clears all sets. I know it. That's why I am asking if there's any other way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are multiple ways, yours is not one of them.

a) pass the value along in the url

```
 $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'example', 'action' => 'view', $this->request->data['Post']['id'], 'var' => $value));
```

yo need to urlescape or even base64encode if your string contains specialchars etc

b) write it to the session and read it in your redirected controller action or view

c) store it somewhere else (db, cache, ...) depending on the type of data you are passing. for longer content the above approaches are not a good option. the reference to it, though, you can safely store in the session for easier lookups in the redirected page.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about the sessions but maybe i can use the URL one. Thanks.